# Store the total json objects into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, rest, gradle, spring-boot

Can I store the total json objects into MongoDB?

Like if I am having the URL of that json.

Can anyone tell in Gradle?

Comment: Yes, you can store the full JSON object in MongoDB.

Comment: Okay thank you but can you provide the any code for that one,wheather i am confusing how it is in gradle

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to directly store the object into MongoDB or will you be using a middleman?

For example, you can write a programs which calls the URL, receives the JSON response, parses it and inserts the data.

You can usually capture the response just by tacking ".json" to the end of the URL. A text file with the JSON response will be generated. Here's a website which generates Java classes from a sample JSON object (just cut/paste the text file into the page's textbox): http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

So, you'd capture the JSON response for a single object, paste it into the website and a Java class (or classes) would be generated. Load this class up in your project. (Of course, you don't have to use Java, but that's what I'm using for this example.)

Then you write a driver which makes a call any JSON URLs that you need, creates a temporary class object for each response, and passes the values to the DB. For multiple JSON responses (which I assume you'll be dealing with), you can accomplish this by dynamically appending the JSON page to the base URL in a for-loop.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://someSite.com + "/someContainer/" + listOfEndpointsStoredInArray.get(i) + ".json");
```

Each time this loop executes, a new JSON response is received. There's various packages available for translating the JSON response into an object, such as GSON.

Stick that response into a String:

```
    HttpClient hc = hcBuilder.build();
     HttpResponse response = hc.execute(request, hccContext);
     HttpEntity body = response.getEntity();
     InputStream is = body.getContent();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("utf-8")));
     String line;
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) { // convert JSON response to String and process the response
       sb.append(line);
```

Pass that response to a helper...

```
  processJSON(sb.toString());
```

...and parse it with something like (using Java here) this:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    anObject = gson.fromJson(resp, MyObject.class); // "MyObject" is the class you generated from the JSON response, using http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/
```

Now you've a Java object which has stored all the values of the JSON object. Pass it to Mongo using your normal JDBC connection, something like this:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String sql = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    try{

    Class.forName("com.mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:mongodb://localhost;databasename=myDatabase;";
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    // begin insertion

    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    stmt=conn.createStatement();

    sql = "INSERT INTO table(value1, value2) "+
          " VALUES (?,?);";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


    pst.setString(1,this.getSomevariable1()); 
    pst.setString(2, this.getSomevariable2());
```

The key here is understanding how serialization works. If you understand this concept, then the solution is trivial. If you don't...well, study up! JSON and SOAP are pretty common, though, so I'm guessing that you won't have a problem picking it up fast.